# How to plot a surface with different functions on different intervals?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, surface

I've got some numerical data fora part of potential energy surface, for which I used bicubic interpolation as explained in this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation). Now I want to plot the surface I get, possibly in such a way that the colors indicate the values of function (sort of heat map).

I have a regular mash of (m x m) points and (m-1)x(m-1) functions.  I have x, y values (at p(0,0) in Wikipedia notation) and function coefficients stored in a file named [coefficients_ci.txt](https://www.mediafire.com/file/tn3he97jyzlhk8f/coefficients_ci.txt/file).

Here is my attempt at this. I get some kind of [surface](https://www.mediafire.com/file/uxmcxjc057auc2j/plot_ci.pdf/file) out, however it's not only surface - the space between xy plane (at z=0) and my surface is filled with colors.
Here is my code:

```py
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


with open ('coefficients_ci.txt', 'r') as all_data:
    lines3 = np.array([line.split() for line in all_data])
all_input_data3 = lines3.astype(float)



def fun(u, v, method, i):


    a00 = all_input_data3[i,3]
    a10 = all_input_data3[i,4]
    a20 = all_input_data3[i,5]
    a30 = all_input_data3[i,6]
    a01 = all_input_data3[i,7]
    a11 = all_input_data3[i,8]
    a21 = all_input_data3[i,9]
    a31 = all_input_data3[i,10]
    a02 = all_input_data3[i,11]    
    a12 = all_input_data3[i,12]
    a22 = all_input_data3[i,13]
    a32 = all_input_data3[i,14]
    a03 = all_input_data3[i,15]    
    a13 = all_input_data3[i,16]    
    a23 = all_input_data3[i,17]    
    a33 = all_input_data3[i,18]   

    x0 = all_input_data3[i, 1]
    y0 = all_input_data3[i, 2]
#    transform coordinates so that starting point is 0,0    
    x = (u-x0)*100
    y = (v-y0)*100


    return a00 + a01*y + a02*y**2 + a03*y**3\
        + a10*x + a11*x*y + a12*x*y**2 + a13*x*y**3\
        + a20*x**2 + a21*x**2*y + a22*x**2*y**2 + a23*x**2*y**3\
        + a30*x**3 + a31*x**3*y + a32*x**3*y**2 + a33*x**3*y**3   


def plotData(method):


    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')


    for i in range(0, len(all_input_data3)):
        print(i)
        u = np.arange(all_input_data3[i, 1], all_input_data3[i, 1]+0.01, 0.0001)
        v = np.arange(all_input_data3[i, 2], all_input_data3[i, 2]+0.01, 0.0001)

        X, Y = np.meshgrid(u, v)
        zs = np.array([fun(u,v, method, i) for u,v in zip(np.ravel(X), np.ravel(Y))])
        print('Calculated function values')        

        Z = zs.reshape(X.shape)
        ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)

        continue
#    plt.show()
    plt.savefig('plot_%s.pdf' % method)
    return
```

I hope my problem is described clear enough and that someone will be able to help me.

Comment: _"I hope my problem is described clear enough"_ — oh well, not that much…. You possibly could get inspiration, and later come back with a more detailed question, looking at the official Matplotlib gallery, that covers both [surface plotting](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/index.html#images-contours-and-fields) and  [3D surfaces](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/index.html#d-plotting). A [non official gallery](https://python-graph-gallery.com/matplotlib/) is also valuable.

Comment: I looked through some of the plots and I tried to use [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/mplot3d/surface3d.html#sphx-glr-gallery-mplot3d-surface3d-py) example. Instead of plotting in the loop I just appended my x, y, z values and tried to plot after the loop is done. But I got out this error: ValueError: Argument Z must be 2-dimensional. Any suggestions how I could get my x, y and z data in the right form?